# error:list index out of range in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I was making a program that counts and prints the number of runs scored, the bowls bowled, the bowler and the batsman which is on strike in a cricket match but when i finished my code:

```
name = input('enter the name of the bowler\n=')  # we ask for the input
    bat_strike = input('enter the name of the batter on strike\n=')
    bat_non_strike = input('enter the name of the batter on the non strike\n=')
    bowls = 6  # this is the max number of bowls in a over
    bowls_bowled = 0
    runs_list = []
    bowls_list = []
    batter_list = []
    batter_list.append(bat_strike)
    for j in range(0, bowls):
        bowl_type = int(input('enter the number corresponding to the option regarding the bowl bowled right now\n1)wide bowl\n2)simple bowl\n3)no ball\n4)dead bowl\n5)1D\n= '))
        if bowl_type == 1:
            bowls_list.append('wd')
            runs_list.append(1)
            batter_list.append(bat_strike)
            bowls += 1
        elif bowl_type == 2:
            run = int(input('enter the number of runs scored on that bowl 1 for 1 run 2 for 2 runs 3 for 3 runs 4 for 4 runs or 0 for a dot ball\n='))
            if run == 1 or run == 3:
                batter_on_strike = input('enter wether the batter on strike is on non strike? y or n\n=')
                if batter_on_strike == 'y':
                    c = bat_strike
                    bat_non_strike = bat_strike
                    bat_non_strike = c
                    batter_list.append(bat_strike)
            runs_list.append(run)
            bowls_list.append(1)
            bowls_bowled += 1
        elif bowl_type == 3:
            bowls_list.append('no ball')
            runs_list.append(1)
            bowls += 1
            batter_list.append(bat_strike)
        elif bowl_type == 4:
            bowls_list.append('dead bowl')
            bowls += 1
            batter_list.append(bat_strike)
        elif bowl_type == 5:
            bowls_list.append('1D')
            bowls += 1
            runs_list.append(1)
            bowls_bowled += 1
            batter_list.append(bat_strike)

    for i in range(0, bowls-1):
        print(f'bowler={name} batter on strike={batter_list[i]} bowl bowled={bowls_list[i]} runs scored={runs_list[i]}')
```

it produces the following error

> print(f'bowler={name} batter on strike={batter_list[i]} bowl bowled={bowls_list[i]} runs scored={runs_list[i]}')
>   IndexError: list index out of range

I want to display the results using a for loop for every bowl but I keep getting this error
anyone has any ideas how can i solve the issue or a better code?

Comment: If `bowl_type` is ever 5, or if it's 2 and the batter on strike or non strike answer isn't `y`, you don't append anything to `batter_list`. So if that ever happens, `batter_list` won't be as long as your other lists.

Comment: yes you are right but after implementing this i got the same error

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "after implementing this", so I can't debug it.

Comment: I mean i made the changes in the code that you suggested but sill i get the same error

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Clearly you didn't fix the problem. You have multiple places where you don't append to `batter_list`, and also multiple places where you don't append to `runs_list`, and maybe others as well. You have to fix all of them, or it still won't work. And I can't tell you which ones you missed without seeing your code. Meanwhile, if you understand the problem, you should be able to debug it yourself. Try running in the debugger, or just adding a `print` statement at the end of the loop to see whether you've built what you think you have.

Answer (score 0):

If `bowl_type` is ever 5, or if it's 2 and the batter on strike or non strike answer isn't `y`, you don't append anything to `batter_list`. So if that ever happens, `batter_list` won't be as long as your other lists.

If, say, all 6 bowls are type 5, then `batter_list` will be empty, so of course `batter_list[4]`, for example, is going to be an error.

It's not clear what you *want* to happen in this case, so it's not obvious how you should fix it.

One possibility is to do a `batter_list.append(None)` in those cases. Or maybe `batter_list.append("n/a")`, or… whatever you want to show up in the `print` later.

Another possibility is to replace all of those separate lists with one list of dicts:

```
bowl_info_list = []
for j in range(0, bowls):
    # ...
    if bowl_type == 1:
        bowl_info_list.append({'bowl': 'wd', 'runs': 1, 'batter': bat_strike})
# ...

for bowl_info in bowl_info_list:
    print(f'bowler={name} batter on strike={bowl_info["batter"]} bowl bowled={bowl_info["bowl"]} runs scored={bowl_info["runs"]}')
```

Or, maybe even better, use a `class` (maybe a `namedtuple` or `@dataclass`) instead of a dict.